# C Idioms and little known facts

Tags: c, arrays, macros

Okay, I've seen many posts here about odd idioms and common practices in C that might not be initially intuitive. Perhaps a few examples are in order

Elements in an array:

```
#define ELEMENTS(x) (sizeof (x) / sizeof (*(x)))
```

[Odd array indexing:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/in-c-arrays-why-is-this-true-a5-5a)

```
a[5] = 5[a]
```

[Single line if/else/while/for safe #defines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/why-are-there-sometimes-meaningless-do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-c-c-macr)

```
#define FOO(X) do { f(X); g(X); } while (0)
#define FOO(X) if (1) { f(X); g(X); } else
```

My question to the expert C programmers out there is: What **idioms**, **practices**, **code snippits**, or **little known facts** show up a lot in C code but might not be very intuitive but offer a good insight into C programming?

Comment: should be community wiki

Comment: Too bad it was closed, bot not being a question...

Answer (score 13):

The "arrow operator" for counting down from `n-1` to `0`:

```
for ( int i = n; i --> 0; ) ...
```

It's not hugely common, but it's an interesting illustration that in some ways the initialize/test/update parts of a `for` loop are convention.  That's the usual pattern, but you can still put any arbitrary expressions in there.

It's also a nice little reminder about how lexical analysis works.

Comment: http://cplusplus.co.il/2009/12/28/the-omnipotent-arrow-operator/

Comment: There is simply no escape from this mighty operator.

Comment: Good for linear search. After all, the first place you should look is the last place you put something.

Comment: I see that this is still here with my sole single downvote.   Despite this answer's popularity, I downvoted it for several reasons, not the least of which is you never explained how it works, or why one would use it given the availability of more orthodox, less obscure, and more easily understandable code.

Answer (score 7):

Since someone will mention it anyway, it might as well be me: [Duff's Device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device).

It's a nice illustration of the way labels work in C, and understanding it gave me an "aha experience" the first time. This is his original code:

```
send(to, from, count)
register short *to, *from;
register count;
{
    register n=(count+7)/8;
    switch(count%8){
    case 0: do{ *to = *from++;
    case 7:     *to = *from++;
    case 6:     *to = *from++;
    case 5:     *to = *from++;
    case 4:     *to = *from++;
    case 3:     *to = *from++;
    case 2:     *to = *from++;
    case 1:     *to = *from++;
        }while(--n>0);
    }
}
```

Today, one wouldn't use `register`, and avoid old-style function definitions.

Comment: Also, as I understand it, you don't want to do this on a modern optimizing compiler---you'll just be getting in its way.

Comment: @dubiousjim I wouldn't think so, if it's a memory-mapped port. A modern optimizing compiler probably would make all these copies into one.

Answer (score 5):

The comma operator, while perfectly well documented (K&R etc.) appears in quite a lot of algorithmic code and is often a surprise to many programmers who have not encountered it before. It is often used to simplify some loop constructs:

```
#define kITERATIONS_MAX 10
int i=0,j=0,array[kITERATIONS_MAX],outArray[kITERATIONS_MAX],temp=0;

for (i=0,j=kITERATIONS_MAX-1; i < kITERATIONS_MAX; i++,j--)
{
temp = array[i]*array[j];
outArray[i]=temp;
}
```

The above code will multiply array elements 0 thru 9 with 9 thru 0 while avoiding nested loops.

When using the comma operator, both the first and second expressions are evaluated. The result of the first expression is ignored and the result of the second expression is returned.

Comment: I use the comma operator in `while` conditions that do two things, usually assignment followed by a test: `while (c = getc(), c != EOF) ...`.

Comment: @DavidRTribble The `c = getc()` evaluates to be equal to `c`, meaning you could just (presumably) use `while((c = getc()) != EOF) ...`

Comment: @RobbieMckennie, That's true, but I find it easier to read the two operations (assignment and comparison) as two separate expressions within the controlling `while` expression.

Comment: @DavidRTribble But it's also less clear what the joined expression evaluates to

Comment: What kind of nested loop is avoided here?